# PHP Script for end user to change Samba password

Tags: linux, samba, password

I'm looking for a PHP script that helps users change their own Samba password on a server. Basically just an interface to `smbpasswd`. The user would ideally enter their samba username, current password and new password (twice). Upon form submission, the script would interface with `smbpasswd` and give them feedback as to whether or not it was a success or if they entered the wrong password or if their new passwords didn't match.

This kind of thing seems like an obvious thing that I was expecting to be out there, but I'm not finding much in my searches...

Comment: Are you using ldap for your account database?  There seem to be several tools that are available if you are using an LDAP backend.

Comment: No LDAP. This is just a basic small business file server.

Answer (score 1):

From the Samba homepage:

```
ChangePassword

This is a web-based tool that allows users to change their unix,samba and squid
password using a web-based interface. Freely available here:
```

http://changepassword.sourceforge.net/

I haven't tested this.

Comment: Tried this. Couldn't get it to compile properly. Anyways, why do you need to compile code just to make a PHP script... ?

Comment: I just looked at it, actually it's not a PHP script but a C program meant to run as a CGI executable.

Comment: Apparently, it's not even good C code judging from the compiler errors :(